# Enumerate files in parent directory

Tags: php, filesystems

I have the following function that enumerates files and directories in a given folder.  It works fine for doing subfolders, but for some reason, it doesn't want to work on a parent directory.  Any ideas why?  I imagine it might be something with PHP's settings or something, but I don't know where to begin.  If it is, I'm out of luck since this is will be running on a cheap shared hosting setup.

Here's how you use the function.  The first parameter is the path to enumerate, and the second parameter is a list of filters to be ignored.  I've tried passing the full path as listed below.  I've tried passing just `..`, `./..` and `realpath('..')`.  Nothing seems to work. I know the function isn't silently failing somehow.  If I manually add a directory to the dirs array, I get a value returned.

```
$projFolder = '/hsphere/local/home/customerid/sitename/foldertoindex';
$items = enumerateDirs($projFolder, array(0 => "Admin", 1 => "inc"));
```

Here's the function itself

```
function enumerateDirs($directory, $filterList)
{
    $handle = opendir($directory);
    while (false !== ($item = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if ($item != "." && $item != ".." && $item != "inc" && array_search($item, $filterList) === false)
        {
            $path = "{$directory->path}/{$item}";

            if (is_dir($item))
            {
                $tmp['name'] = $item;
                $dirs[$item] = $tmp;
                unset($tmp);
            }
            elseif (is_file($item))
            {
                $tmp['name'] = $item;
                $files[] = $tmp;
                unset($tmp);
            }
        }
    }

    ksort($dirs, SORT_STRING);
    sort($dirs);

    ksort($files, SORT_STRING);
    sort($files);

    return array("dirs" => $dirs, "files" => $files);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up opendir and dir. You also need to pass the full path (including the directory component) to is_dir and is_file. (I assume that's what you meant to do with $path.) Otherwise, the functions will look for the corresponding file system objects in the script file's directory.

Try this for a quick fix:

```
<?php

function enumerateDirs($directory, $filterList)
{
    $handle = dir($directory);

    while (false !== ($item = $handle->read()))
    {
        if ($item != "." && $item != ".." && $item != "inc" && array_search($item, $filterList) === false)
        {
            $path = "{$handle->path}/{$item}";

            $tmp['name'] = $item;

            if (is_dir($path))
            {
                $dirs[] = $tmp;
            }
            elseif (is_file($path))
            {
                $files[] = $tmp;
            }

            unset($tmp);
        }
    }

    $handle->close();

    /* Anonymous functions will need PHP 5.3+. If your version is older, take a
     * look at create_function
     */
    $sortFunc = function ($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']); };

    usort($dirs, $sortFunc);    
    usort($files, $sortFunc);

    return array("dirs" => $dirs, "files" => $files);
}

$ret = enumerateDirs('../', array());

var_dump($ret);
```

Note: $files or $dirs might be not set after the while loop. (There might be no files or directories.) In that case, usort will throw an error. You should check for that in some way.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Since this is a side project, I can't check until later.  Will let you know, but what you're saying makes sense (and is probably right).